# mremap and page fauls

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, virtual-memory, page-tables

Looking at mremap()'s impl at the kernel, it looks like it does move and relocates the memory pages, it also flushes the tlb if needed and so on.
However, in reality, it appears that it does not, but rather a page fault generated later on will do the actual mapping.

so my question is - why is that, if the code specifically calls move_page_tables, move_ptes and flush_tlb if needed.

I've made a test to confirm,

I have 2 memory chunks allocated by a call to mmap.
both identical in size, flags are equal and accessible, anonymous as I don't need a file and shared to allow multiple mapping of the same region:

```
a = mmap(NULL, buffs_size, PROT_READ| PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
b = mmap(NULL, buffs_size, PROT_READ| PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

Now, I call mremap:

```
mremap(a, 0, buff_size, MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED,  b)
```

At that point, b contains the contents of a, however, it appears that mremap did not mapped the pages, a page fault occured when I've accessed b, mapped the memory to those of a, and continue execution.

Any ideas, or code pointers to where is this decision located?